# Failed to execute 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rect

I'm using an PNG as a background pattern for a series of rectangles in an HTML5 Canvas that are acting as an audio visualizer, however, I am receiving an Uncaught TypeError with my code:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="analyser_render"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('analyser_render');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
pattern = ctx.createPattern("images/analyser.png", "repeat-x");
ctx.fillStyle = pattern;

bars = 30;
for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
     bar_x = i * 10;
     bar_width = 9;
     bar_height = -(dataArray[i] / 2);
     ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
}
```

This is only a portion of my actual code, the portions that include the creation of the rectangles.  The dataArray variable is part of the Web Audio API, and is not part of the issue in question.

Answer (score 0):

For an image to be loaded properly, you need to create an image object and then set its source.

```
img = new Image();
img.src = 'images/analyser.png';
```

then in the createPattern, call the image object

```
pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, "repeat-x");
```

Comment: to properly load an image you will also need to use the `onload` callback as image loading is asynchronous.

Comment: Not necessarily @KenFyrstenberg, I simply put the above code into my functions and it worked the way I wanted it to without any onload. Then again, the img declaration was in an INIT function, and the createPattern was in a looping requestAnimationFrame function.  So there may lie the confusion.

Comment: That is because the image is cached in your browser and loading it locally. When you put this code online and an user loads it the first time the image may or may not be loaded in time. This is why onload *must* be handled properly.

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg is correct. You're just gambling on proper execution if you don't use image.onload.